# error in webpack configuration

Tags: node.js, webpack

Sorry, for the question - new to Node, ES5/ES6 etc. I don't understand how to write a piece of code with es3 [- name for regular JavaScript]. In order to test some stuff, I did what my colleagues do - coded one script using es6 vocabulary and used webpack to produce javascript with maps suitable for node.
Our tests are written the same way, and they compile and run OK.

I only changed filename of the "entry" and "output", and left the rest.

When I run my package: $npm run experiment it tells me:

```
> my-api@0.5.1 experiment /home/shmukler/myproject/my-api/server
> webpack --config webpack.experiment.config.js && NODE_ENV=development && JWT_AUTH=disable test-build/compiled.js

ts-loader: Using typescript@1.7.3 and /home/shmukler/myprojectk/my-api/server/tsconfig.json
Hash: bd09c19cb3303df8f633
Version: webpack 1.12.9
Time: 3628ms
      Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    compiled.js  19.5 kB       0  [emitted]  main
compiled.js.map  29.9 kB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 8 hidden modules
sh: 1: test-build/compiled.js: Permission denied
```

How can I find out what is causing the Permission denied error?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. Apparently webpack does NOT automatically add executable permission to the output. chmod a+x gets rid of that error. :)